# xaml button focus with button mouse over

Tags: wpf, xaml

I created a button style for my project.  I want the button to flash when the user moves the cursor over it.  I do it with this code:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="#808000" To="#ffaec9" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
             </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
     </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

I also want then user focus button it to also flash. But if I create similar code for IsFocused property will not work as I want. Can i use the property concatenation in Property attribute of tag trigger? Can i create sequence of triggers (trigger1 work if it worked before triпger2 and will not work if worked trigger3)?

Comment: Why arent you considering Multi-Triggers or Visual State Managers in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this state, it will work on your button

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
      <Storyboard>
         <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
      </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```